# Wordpress loop for multiple custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

Looking for a way to loop through multiple custom post types and get the 4 most recent posts.

I have the below but doesn't quite work as if you 2 posts of the same post type, it'll show the most recent rather than showing most recent of ALL custom posts.

```
$args = array('post_type' => array('cs_trainee', 'cs_graduates', 'cs_pros', 'sd_trainee', 'sd_graduates'), 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC');
$careers = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the query_posts parameters a bit....

```
query_posts( array(
 'post_type' => array( 'post', 'report', 'opinion', bookmark' ),
 'cat' => 3,
 'orderby' => 'date',
 'order' => 'DESC',
 'showposts' => 5 )
 );
```

That should take care of it for you.

Comment: This worked great however the orderby and order doesn't seem to do anything. Trying to order by post date and in DESC order but makes no difference - do you know why?

Comment: I have modified query_posts so you can try this.